# NoReverseMatch Error, Django can't verify the edit page

Tags: class, django-forms

$I have no solution for this error , please i need support, it gives noreversematch and it seems it cant reach my edit-page , the following if full details of the coding , thank you

$ Edit link to edit page:

```
{% if post.created_by == user %}
   <div class="mt-3">
   <a class="btn btn-success float-end" 
      href="{% url 'edit_post' post.topic.board.pk post.topic.pk post.pk %}">Edit</a>
   </div>
{% endif %}
```

$ views.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
  model = Post
  fields = ['message']
  template_name = 'edit_post.html'
  pk_url_kwarg = 'post_id'
  context_object_name = 'post'
  def form_valid(self, form):
    post = form.save(commit=False)
    post.updated_by = self.request.user
    post.updated_date = timezone.now()
    post.save()
    return redirect('topic_posts', board_id=post.topic.board.pk, topic_id=post.topic.pk)
```

$ urls.py

```
path('<int:board_id>/topics/<int:topic_id>/posts/<int:post_id/edit', 
views.PostUpdateView.as_view(), name="edit_post"),
```

$html of the edit-page

```
<div class="container container-newtopic w-50">
    <h1>Edit Post</h1>
    <br>
    {% include 'parts/alerts.html' %}
    <div aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb n1-head">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'boards' %}">Boards</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'topics' post.topic.board.pk 
                 %}">
                {{post.topic.board.name}}</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page"><a href="">Edit 
                 Post</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
     <form method="POST" action="" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}">
        {% include 'includes/form.html' %}

        <button type="submit" name="btnaddtopicdj" 
            class="btn main-btn w-100 rounded-pill mt-5">Save Changes
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

$ error message:

```
NoReverseMatch at /boards/3/topics/20
Reverse for 'edit_post' with arguments '(3, 20, 23)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: 
['boards/(?P<board_id>[0-9]+)/topics/(?P<topic_id>[0-9]+)/posts/<int:post_id/edit\\Z']

Reverse for 'edit_post' with arguments '(3, 20, 23)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: 
['boards/(?P<board_id>[0-9]+)/topics/(?P<topic_id>[0-9]+)/posts/<int:post_id/edit\\Z']

 href="{% url 'edit_post' post.topic.board.pk post.topic.pk post.pk %}">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Should `path('<int:board_id>/topics/<int:topic_id>/posts/<int:post_id/edit'` be `path('<int:board_id>/topics/<int:topic_id>/posts/<int:post_id>/edit'`?

Comment: then what it should be ?!